# How to convert to String^ type

Tags: visual-studio-2013, c++-cx

I am newbie to programming for windows phone, so I have a question. How can i convert type `String` to its pointer type(`String^`)? here's fragment from sample of windows phone 8.1 program

```
Uri^ uri;
String^ ready;
TryGetUri(L"http://abotstars.16mb.com/images", &uri);
filter->CacheControl->ReadBehavior = HttpCacheReadBehavior::Default;
filter->CacheControl->WriteBehavior = HttpCacheWriteBehavior::Default;

create_task(httpClient->GetAsync(uri), cancellationTokenSource.get_token()).then([=](HttpResponseMessage^ response)
{

}, task_continuation_context::use_current()).then([=](task<HttpResponseMessage^> previousTask)
{

    // Check if any previous task threw an exception.
    HttpResponseMessage^ response = previousTask.get();

    ready = response->Source.ToString();

}); 
// Create a notification for the Square310x310 tile using one of the available templates for the size.
auto tileContent = TileContentFactory::CreateTileSquare310x310Text09();
tileContent->TextHeadingWrap->Text = "Hello World! My very own tile notification";
```

I want to put response that come from server to Tile. But IntelliSense(VS2013) said, that the left value can't be changed. It says something about lambda value. I don't really know what it wants, but I tried different ways to have this value and always get different errors. What I do wrong?
Sorry for Russian language of SDK :D. So here's an error which show that it can't convert `String^`

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fztz8.png

Comment: This is C++/CLI not C++. Please tag your question appropriately.

Comment: Is this a variant of c++? Please post the exact error statement and line number. If the lambda error is seen on the last line, you might have to call SetText() function instead of assigning to Text.

Comment: This is not CLI for real.. It's C++/CX. But it don't let to type this :\

Comment: IntelliSense is not the compiler. You don't have to treat intellisense errors like compiler errors. Is there a compiler error? What does it say?

Comment: @MariusBancila , already added. It is said that it can't convert a type

Comment: @MariusBancila , here is an error which shows in some cases, when i change my code. http://s29.postimg.org/myo6995qf/image.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone have similar question - problem was here:

```
create_task(httpClient->GetAsync(uri), cancellationTokenSource.get_token()).then([=](HttpResponseMessage^ response)
{

}
```

There were empty brackets.